# Was plot.ACF removed from the front end of NLME? Or did I change some setting on accident?

Tags: r, nlme

I'm using R to analyze a linear mixed effects model (nlme::lme). I want to plot the ACF values with a dashed line at the alpha level (as plot.ACF does).

After I `require(nlme)`, I can run ACF, but plot.ACF is still not available. I can access it via `nlme:::plot.ACF` though, meaning it's designated as a hidden function. Was this feature of the package shelved for some reason? If not, is there another likely explanation? Does anyone know a way in which I can make the package export it (even after updating)?

Comment: Don't know if it changed or not, but because it's object-oriented, just `plot` (which isn't hidden) will run `plot.ACF` on any ACF object.

Comment: It's not removed - you can always check on CRAN yourself if you're unsure

Comment: @Umaomamaomao, the question isn't if it's removed, but if it's now hidden (which it is in 3.1-137) and if so, why and what to do about it.

Comment: @Aaron I'm so incredibly sorry. Can you ever forgive me?

Comment: @Umaomamaomao: I'm assuming you're in jest, but either way, of course! :)

Comment: @42- I think it's a terminology issue; `plot.ACF` is indeed not exported in 3.1-137.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is hidden from the front end of the `nlme` package (ie, not exported); I don't know if this is a change or not.

```
> nlme::plot.ACF
Error: 'plot.ACF' is not an exported object from 'namespace:nlme'
```

However, you can access the help for it using `?plot.ACF`, where it demonstrates the following usage:

> ```
> ## S3 method for class 'ACF'
> plot(x, alpha, xlab, ylab, grid, ...)
> ```

Note that it's not suggesting using `plot.ACF` but instead just `plot`. This works because the `plot` function is object-oriented, so will call `plot.ACF` behind the scenes whenever `plot` is called on an `ACF` object.

That is, to plot an `ACF` object you should just type `plot`, not `plot.ACF`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the plot.ACF function was never exported. The earliest version of nlme from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/nlme/ that I could find with a NAMESPACE file was nlme_3.1-40 (Date: 2003-05-16), and that function would have been invisible (at the console). It still would have been accessible with the `methods` function and the code would have been available with the triple dot mechanism (`:::`) or `getAnywhere` functions.

```
getAnywhere("plot.ACF")  Retruns formal parameters, funciton body and information about functions environment
getS3method("plot", "ACF")  # returns same code as getAnywhere

x <- methods(class="ACF")
str(x)
#--------------
 'MethodsFunction' chr "plot.ACF"
 - attr(*, "info")='data.frame':    1 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ visible: logi FALSE
  ..$ from   : Factor w/ 1 level "registered S3method": 1
  ..$ generic: chr "plot"
  ..$ isS4   : logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "byclass")= logi TRUE
```

I apologize for my earlier, somewhat snarky comment, because on re-reading your post it appears you do understand that the functions is available, just not visible. What's still unclear is why you thought it was ever visible.

If you want to have plot.ACF exported, you could add it to the list of exported functions in the NAMESPACE file and rebuild the package. Or you could export on the fly with:

```
plot.ACF <- getAnywhere("plot.ACF")
```

Comment: Hi @42-, nice detective work and a great example of being friendly and welcoming to new contributors, thanks!